# Trouble aligning the object in render view

Tags: modeling, mesh, origin

I was moving objects in Edit mode when I should have been moving them in object mode but now I cannot seem to correct the positions.

[image]

I've tried setting the origin, but it hasn't worked for me.

[image]

How do I do this? [image: One example of the issue.]

Comment: I should say that applying transformations also doesn't seem to help.

Comment: There should be Align option to align objects. You may also use SnapTo to align.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Aligning objects doesn't change anything, though I might be doing it wrong.

Comment: Change the displacement method to bump instead of true displacement